# Update query - optimisation

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am working on update query.but my query tooks more run time.

Is there any possibility to modify the below query?

```
UPDATE 
BDM.CUST_DIM_SCD2
SET
EFF_TO_TMS =current_timestamp -2,
CUR_ROW_IND =0
WHERE
CUST_CD = (SELECT CUST_CD FROM BDM.CUST_DIM_SCD2 WHERE  CUR_ROW_IND =1  AND CUST_CD IN  (SELECT CUST_CD FROM BDM.TEMP_CUST_DIM_UPDATE ))
 AND
CUST_UNIT_CD=(SELECT CUST_CD FROM BDM.CUST_DIM_SCD2  WHERE CUR_ROW_IND =1 AND CUST_UNIT_CD IN  (SELECT CUST_UNIT_CD FROM BDM.TEMP_CUST_DIM_UPDATE ))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked query plan for this SQL?

Comment: The both nested sub queries look very similar. Try to use just one occurrence and convert this into updatable join.

Comment: @Renat no I am not checked

Comment: @ibre5041no it's not same .we are taking cust_cd and cust_unit_cd in the sub queries.

Comment: is your second condition right? CUST_UNIT_CD=(SELECT CUST_CD ... why isn't it CUST_UNIT_CD=(SELECT CUST_UNIT_CD ... ?

Comment: Yes it's correct @CarlosSR

Comment: What's the database? The optimization can vary from engine to engine.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried rewriting Your query using joins instead of subqueries? I think it may result with less data being processed and better performance. The end query would look somewhat like this:

```sql
UPDATE cust
SET
    EFF_TO_TMS =current_timestamp -2,
    CUR_ROW_IND =0
FROM BDM.CUST_DIM_SCD2 cust
    -- instead of CUST_CD clause
    INNER JOIN BDM.CUST_DIM_SCD2 c2 on cust.CUST_CD = c2.CUST_CD and c2.CUR_ROW_IND =1
    INNER JOIN BDM.TEMP_CUST_DIM_UPDATE c2tmp on c2.CUST_CD = c2tmp.CUST_CD
    -- instead of CUST_UNIT_CD clause
    INNER JOIN BDM.CUST_DIM_SCD2 c3 on cust.CUST_UNIT_CD = c3.CUST_CD and c3.CUR_ROW_IND =1
    INNER JOIN BDM.TEMP_CUST_DIM_UPDATE c3tmp on c3.CUST_CD = c3tmp.CUST_CD
```